# FFT based algorithm for special matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

[Contest problems with connections to deeper mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69737/contest-problems-with-connections-to-deeper-mathematics)

This question is with regard to Elkies' answer to the above post.

Vandermonde determinant can be computed using FFT techniques.

Can Moore determinant(including modulo some integer) be computed using FFT techniques?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly my field, but I think that the same techniques used for Vandermonde's determinant work for Moore's and on finite rings (with the added complication of using FFTs over rings).

A good reference is Bini and Pan, *Polynomial and matrix computations*.