# Metric extensions of Littlewood's conjecture

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation

Littlewood's conjecture on simultaneous rational approximation to a pair of real numbers,
$$
\liminf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \, n \cdot \mathrm{dist}(n\alpha,\mathbb{Z}) \cdot \mathrm{dist}(n\beta, \mathbb{Z}) = 0,
$$
has remained one of the outstanding open problems in Diophantine Approximations. A natural extension of it, considered by Cassels and Swinnerton-Dyer in the 1950s, turns out exactly equivalent to a conjectured rigidity property in higher rank hyperbolic homogeneous dynamics: all bounded orbits of the Weyl chamber flow on $\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ are closed (or, one could say, 'periodic'). The best result on the problem, the Einsiedler-Katok-Lindenstrauss theorem that the conjecture holds for all pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$ outside of a set of zero Hausdorff dimension, has come from this ergodic theory avenue. However, special cases such as $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ have remained unsolved.

It is also possible to extend the problem in a direction completely disjoint from homogeneous dynamics. Observe that if $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a counterexample to Littlewood's conjecture then, for a large enough constant $C < \infty$, 
$$
P_n : \, (x_n,y_n) =  (C\{n\alpha\}, C \{n\beta\}) \in \mathbb{R}^2 
$$
gives an infinite bounded sequence of points in the plane (or a torus, if one prefers), such that
$$
|x_n-x_m| |y_n-y_m| \geq \frac{1}{|n-m|}
$$
for all $n \neq m$.

**Question:** *Does such an infinite bounded sequence exist? Or is this extension of Littlewood's conjecture considered anywhere?*

Note that, as explained by Ilya Bogdanov solving [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187440/is-there-a-bounded-sequence-of-points-in-the-plane-with-pairwise-distances-at-le) of mine, such a sequence *does* exist if one weakens the condition to
$$
\max(|x_n-x_m|^2, |y_n-y_m|^2) \geq \frac{1}{|n-m|}.
$$